# "The specified module could not be found" asp.net mvc app on IIS 7, windows server 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, 64-bit

We have an ASP.NET MVC application working on a 32bit Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.

After deploying it on a 64bit Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 it stopped working. We get the following error:

"Could not load file or assembly '###.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found"

The dll is a 3rd party dll, and we can not re-compile it.
We tried putting it in every possible directory but nothing helped. It appears in the Fusion log and the last line of this files log contains "IL assembly loaded from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary .....".

The application pool runs in Integrated mode and "Enable 32-bit applications" is set to True.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Katie D.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have MVC3 installed? It is a separate install.

Maybe check your 3rd party dll with a tool like reflector to see what it relies on.

Comment: Yeah MVC 3 is intalled. I checked the dependencies of the 3rd party dll, but nothing seemed missing.